# I have nodejs project, which allows users to upload photos. How can I host them. I need an example

Tags: node.js, photo

Users should upload photos.
They should be hosted somewhere else.
Only the photo hosting, no photo transformation needed.
What should I use, and how to use it.

Cloudinary.
It works, but I need a very simple solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The informations are complete.